# Ubuntu 16.04 no wifi & no usb on Lenovo Thinkpad

Tags: networking, usb, lenovo, thinkpad

My wife’s Thinkpad has been working fine with 16.04 till this week when the wifi stopped. I tried sudo lshw -class network & got;

```
*-network UNCLAAIMED
    description: Wireless controller
    product: wireless 7260
    vendor: Intel corporation
     physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: b0:c0:90:5c:1c:d5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master
```

...
I then plugged in a usb stick in to copy it, but found that the usb is also not working. Can you help please? d0m.

Comment: Probably it was an interrupted upgrade. Connect by wire and run sudo apt upgrade.

Comment: There isn't a wire option, the Thinkpad doesn’t have network port.

Comment: Then you are in trouble. I suggest to re-install.

Comment: Can't reinstall cos I need to the usb port to put the stick with Ubuntu on it. Is there a rollback option?

Comment: There is no rollback option. USB port will work for booting.